# Application intent = readonly SQL Server connection error

Tags: sql-server, web-config, alwayson

I want to connect to an availability group (listener ip) including 4 different database servers. In my connection string, I specify

```
application intent = readonly
```

attribute to connect as read-only. But it fails with a

> database connection error

There are two different cases:

- when I use a database ip instead of listener ip, I can connect to the database
- when I remove `application intent = readonly`, I can connect to the database

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try writing without spaces; "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly"

[Using Connection String Keywords with SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client)